# Can't change character or do any missions

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, xbox-one

In single player, the last mission I completed was Lamar Down.  Now whenever I load the game, I am stuck as Michael and cannot select another character, or start any random missions.

So far this is what I've tried, to no avail:

- calling everyone in my contacts list.  I did get through to Dave and had a conversation about having made it out after The Wrap Up mission, but this didn't change anything
- jumped in a taxi and took a mission
- went into GTA online and tried to select one of the other players from there; it just loads single player as Michael
- drove a full circuit of the island to see if anything triggered (it didn't)
- did a replay of a previous mission

Anyone else having this problem?  I don't have a previous save and there's no way I'm starting from the beginning again when I'm so close to the end of the game!  I did that once already when I changed from 360 to Xbox One!

### ** EDIT **

Here is a response from Rockstar Support:

> Hello John,
>
> We are sorry to hear that you are still experiencing troubles with our
>   game on the Xbox One. We would like to have you try the following
>   steps to help resolve the troubles you are experiencing:
>
> **Remove your profile from the console.**
>
> Go to Home screen.
>
> Press the Menu button on your controller.
>
> Select Settings.
>
> Scroll to the right. Under OTHER PEOPLE, select Remove accounts.
>
> Select the account that you want to remove, and then select Choose
>   this person.
>
> Select Remove from this Xbox to confirm.
>
> When you’re finished, select Close.
>
> **Uninstall the Game.**
>
> Start from Home (press the Xbox button on your controller to go Home).
>
> Go to My games and apps.
>
> Highlight the content that you want to uninstall.
>
> Press the Menu button on your controller.
>
> Select Uninstall.
>
> **Hold the power button on the console until it shuts off then unplug the power cord for 30 seconds.**
>
> **Once console is restarted, download your profile.**
>
> Select Sign in.
>
> Sign into your gamer tag.
>
> Allow your profile to download.
>
> **Disconnect from your internet.**
>
> Go to Home screen.
>
> Press the Menu button on your controller.
>
> Select Settings.
>
> Select Network.
>
> Select Disconnect.
>
> **Install the game.**
>
> **Reconnect to the Internet and start the game to download the update.**
>
> After the game is finished updating, please check to see if your issue
>   is still occurring. If you continue to have troubles, please do not
>   hesitate to let us know.
>
> Best regards,
>
> Sobin J. Rockstar Support

I'll test this tonight; if it works I'll post it as the answer.  Maybe it'll help someone else in the future.

Comment: Which console are you using?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, playing on PC. I only use autosave, but if you use manual saving try to reload an older one.

Comment: @ardaozkal XBox One, although I've noticed from other forums that this seems to be a recurring problem on all consoles and PC

Comment: @Izzo I rely on autosave, unfortunately.  I do have a previous manual save but it's from much earlier in the game, on Franklin's 1st assassination mission when trying to play the market!

Comment: Hi jayrdi, could you update your question and provide a solution as answer if it worked for you, your question as it stands is attracting NAA's.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, been putting it off because it's quite a big process. Just been playing multiplayer instead! I'll give it a try this weekend and post results

Comment: Did this end up working for you?

Comment: A game update fixed it in the end, I think it had the same effect as refreshing the game by reinstalling it. I was putting off the solution offered by Rockstar Support because it was a hassle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kept putting off the whole uninstalling the game and resetting the console because it was a pain and played something else. However, the problem was fixed when I went back to play the game at a later date and there was an update. I'm guessing this refreshed the install somehow in the same way that reinstalling the game would and that there had also been a console update which had reset any cached information.

If anyone does try the "official" method listed above and finds it to work (rather than waiting for updates), then write it here as an answer and I'll change the accepted answer to be that one.